# Monotonicity of trigonometric function

Tags: functions, trigonometry, monotone-functions

Consider the function
$$f(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{\sin((2k+1)x)}$$
with $k$ a positive integer. It seems that $f$ is strictly increasing in $[0,\frac{\pi}{2(2k+1)}]$.  Is there some easy proof of this monotonicity property that does not invole differentiation (through suitable inequalities)?

Comment: I think you mean that $f$ is strictly **increasing** in $[0, \frac{\pi}{2k+1}]$. The [Desmos graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/dlh5gg4fvf) shows that this is not true for $k=1$.

Comment: @TobyMak Yes, sorry I will correct the question. I am actually looking for the minimum.

Comment: @TobyMak Not up to $\pi/(2k+1)$. Up to half the distance $\pi/(2(2k+1))$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\begin{aligned}\frac{\sin(x)}{\sin((k+1)x)}&=\frac{\sin(x)}{\sin(kx)\cos(x)+\cos(kx)\sin(x)}\\
&=\frac{1}{\frac{\sin(kx)}{\sin(x)}\cos(x)+\cos(kx)}
\end{aligned}$$

Hence: $$\begin{aligned}\frac{\sin(x)}{\sin(kx)}\text{ increasing}&\iff\frac{\sin(kx)}{\sin(x)}\text{ decreasing}\\
&\Rightarrow \frac{\sin(kx)}{\sin(x)}\cos(x)\text{ decreasing}\\
&\iff\frac{\sin(kx)}{\sin(x)}\cos(x)+\cos(kx)\text{ decreasing}\\
&\iff\frac1{\frac{\sin(kx)}{\sin(x)}\cos(x)+\cos(kx)}\text{ increasing}\\
\\
&\iff\frac{\sin(x)}{\sin((k+1)x)}\text{ increasing}\\
\end{aligned}$$

Let $P(k)$ denote the proposition that $\frac{\sin(x)}{\sin(kx)}$ is increasing. Hence, we've shown that $P(k)\rightarrow P(k+1)$. So, we may use $P(1)$ (as shown in **@Kusma's** answer) to inductively prove that $\frac{\sin(x)}{\sin((2k+1)x)}$ is increasing over $[0,\frac{\pi}{2(2k+1)}]$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Thank you! This provides a recursive relation to show that all functions $\frac{\sin(kx)}{sin(x)}$ are decreasing. So it solves the full problem. I will accept this answer! Maybe you  could possibly add the details for future reference.

Comment: @RTJ Which details would you like?

Comment: Well, an induction argument can be used i.e. starting from $\sin(2x)/sinx$ we can recursively show using your argument that all these functions are decreasing.

Comment: Sure thing, I'll do that now.

Comment: @RTJ I'm not entirely convinced there's enough to form a full inductive argument since we've shown that $P(2k+1)\rightarrow P(2k)$ but I don't think we've proven that $P(2k)\rightarrow P(2k+1)$.

Comment: It's there. You don't need to distinguish between even and odd cases since $\frac{\sin((k+1)x)}{\sin(x)}=\frac{\sin(kx)}{\sin(x)}\cos(x)+\cos(kx)$. So, if $=\frac{\sin(kx)}{\sin(x)}$ is decreasing so is $\frac{\sin((k+1)x)}{\sin(x)}$.

Comment: I noticed a flaw in this proof - if $f(k,x)\cos(x)+\cos(2kx)$ is decreasing, this doesn't imply that $f(k,x)$ is also decreasing (for instance take $f(k,x)=\sec(x)$). All we can say is that if $\cos(2kx)$ is decreasing then so too is $f(k,x)\cos(x)+\cos(2kx)$. I'll try to fix this.

Comment: But we are working the other way around, i.e. if $f(k,x)$ is decreasing then we prove that $f(k+1,x)$ is also decreasing. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @RTJ It's fine now - I'd overcomplicated it but fixed it now.

Answer (score 4):

You have $\sin2x=2\sin x \cos x$ and $\sin 3x=\sin x \cos 2x + \cos x \sin 2x =\sin x (\cos 2 x + 2 \cos^2 x)$, and similar formulas for higher $\sin (kx)$. Then 
$$\frac{\sin(3x)}{\sin x} = \cos 2 x + 2\cos^2x
$$
where the RHS is decreasing in $x$ and positive as long as $\cos 2x>0$. That gives you an interval where $\frac{\sin x}{\sin 3x}$ is increasing.

Of course turning this into a proof for general $k$ is a lot more complicated than differentiating, but it should be possible. (You don't get non-integer $k$, though).